Consequence of Fejer's theorem
I'm reading calculus conspect of my university and that's how Fejer's theorem is stated: let $f \in C(T)$ is a continous, $2\pi$ periodic function, then $\sigma_N(f) \xrightarrow{\xrightarrow{n}} f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. And I wanna understand the proof of it's consequence: let let $f \in C(T)$ is a continous, $2\pi$ periodic function, $\hat{f}(n)=o(\frac{1}{|n|})$, then the Fourier series of $f$: $S(f,x)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
Here is the proof: by Fejer's theorem, $\sigma_N(f) \xrightarrow{\xrightarrow{n}} f$, then it's enough to show that $S_n(f) - \sigma_{n-1}(f) \xrightarrow{\xrightarrow{n}} f$ (question $(1?)$ - why?). After that, we have: $|S_n(f(x)) - \sigma_{n-1}(f,x)| = (2?) |\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{\frac{|k|}{n}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}}| \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{|k||\hat{f(k)}|}$. we have that $|k\hat{f(k)}| = o(1)$, hence $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}|k\hat{f}(k)| = o(1)$ as $k$ approaches infinity. hence $||Sn(f) − \sigma_{n−1}(f)||_{\infty} \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{|k\hat{f}(k)|} \to 0$
please help me understand (1) and (2) questions, any help would be appreciated!
